# Why is Edoardo angry with Antonio?

Tags: plot-explanation, i-am-love

In the movie [I Am Love](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1226236/), before his death, when Edoardo finds out about Emma and Antonio, he says to Emma:

> You are lying. You are just like others. You are just like Gianluca, Papa, Antonio..
>
> You even gave him our Ukha

Why is he angry with Antonio? He didn't know about their affair until that moment. You don't use "*You are just like others*" unless you are/feel betrayed by "*others*" in the first place.

To me, Edoardo seemed to be fond of Antonio throughout the movie. From when did he grow a grudge against him?